# Solving for one variable in a bi-variable equation.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need to solve for the variable $r$ in the equation:

$$g = \sqrt{r^2 - 2r}$$

After I square both sides of the equation, I'm lost on how to isolate the variable $r$ from the binomial on the right side of the equation.

Comment: It's already solved for $g$.  I presume you want to solve for $r$.  After squaring both sides, you have a quadratic equation.  Do you know how to solve quadratic equations?

Comment: The problem that I have is once I square the variable g and the square root expression, I have g^2 on the left, and the expression r^2 - 2r on the right side of the equation. When I subtract r^2 - 2r and shift it to the right side of the equation I have g^2 - r^2 - 2r=0. This would be simple if the second term were 4gr. Then, I could factor it & isolate the r [ please forgive me-I'm trying to solve for the r variable. ] However,  the 2r term leaves me baffled.

Comment: Does it help to write it as $r^2 - 2 r - g^2 = 0$?

Comment: No, that's where I'm stuck at.

Comment: Please fix your question. It says that you "need to solve for the variable $g$", but in these comments you said that you're "trying to solve for the $r$ variable".

Comment: How would you solve $r^2 - 2 r - 9 = 0$?

Comment: Correction: need to solve for the r-variable.

Comment: How about $r^2 - 2r + 1 = 10$?

Comment: PM 2Ring, please explain how the equation can be expressed as $r^2 - 2r + 1 = 10$?

Comment: I just modified Robert's equation, which is related to your equation, but a little simpler because there's only one variable. We want to know if you know how to solve this simpler equation.

Comment: BTW, when you subtract $r^2 - 2r$ and shift it to the right side of the equation you should get $g^2 - r^2 + 2r=0$

Comment: @PM 2Ring, to solve $r^2 - 2r +1 = 10$, I would subtract 10 from both sides of the equation and derive $r^2 - 2r - 9 =0$. Apply the quadratic equation, and come up $1+/- sqrt (10) as my answer.

Comment: So if you can apply the quadratic formula to $r^2 - 2 r - 9$, you can apply the same formula with $g^2$ instead of $9$.

Comment: Another way is to notice that $r^2 - 2r + 1 = (r - 1)^2$, so $(r - 1) = \pm \sqrt{10}$ hence $r = 1 \pm \sqrt{10}$

Comment: @user353858 Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, you can use the standard quadratic formula for this.

Given
$$g = \sqrt{r^2 - 2r}$$

Square both sides
$$g^2 = r^2 - 2r$$

Rearrange
$$r^2 - 2r - g^2 = 0$$

Now we have a quadratic equation in $r$: $ar^2 + br + c = 0$, with $a=1$, $b=-2$, and $c=-g^2$, so we can plug those $a, b, c$ values into the quadratic formula
$$r = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}$$
Which gives us
$$r = \frac{2 \pm \sqrt{4 + 4g^2}}{2} = 1 \pm \sqrt{1 + g^2}$$

---

But we don't really need to use the quadratic formula here. Instead, we can use a technique known as completing the square.

We know that for any $u, v$ 
$$(u + v)^2 = u^2 + 2uv + v^2$$
So if we have an expression like
$$u^2 + 2uv = z$$
We can add $v^2$ to both sides:
$$u^2 + 2uv + v^2 = z + v^2$$
So
$$(u + v)^2 = z + v^2$$
Or
$$u + v = \pm \sqrt{z + v^2}$$

---

Getting back to the squared form of the original equation

$$g^2 = r^2 - 2r$$
The coefficient of the $r$ term is $-2$. That corresponds to $2v=-2$ in the previous section, that is, $v=-1$, so we can add $(-1)^2$ to both sides to complete the square:
$$g^2 + 1 = r^2 - 2r + 1 = (r - 1)^2$$
So 
$$r - 1 = \pm \sqrt{g^2 + 1}$$
Or
$$r = 1 \pm \sqrt{g^2 + 1}$$

Answer (score 0):

You have to solve the following system

$$\begin{cases} r^2 - 2r\geq0\\ r^2 - 2r-g^2=0 \end{cases}$$

to solve $r^2 - 2r-g^2=0$ take a look here

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation